# psycopg2 to redshift timing out but sql client connects ok

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have connected a SQL client to a Redshift instance without issue, using basic user, pass, and SSH.

The Redshift instance is in a VPC but has an associated security group that allows SSH connections for specific IP addresses. The Redshift instance is also publicly available. Again, the SQL client connects just fine.

Even though the SQL client was connecting fine I added an inbound rule to allow TCP traffic at 5439 from my IP Address.

Python still code does not connect. It throws this error.

```
connection to server at "redshift-instance.asdf.us-west-14.redshift.amazonaws.com" (xx.xx.xxx.xxx), port 5439 failed: Operation timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

The code is below:

```
import psycopg2


conf = {
    "dbname": "something",
    "host": "something",
    "port": 5439, # tried this and SSH forwarded port 4450
    "user": "something",
    "password": "something",
}


def create_conn(*args, **kwargs):
    config = kwargs["config"]
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=config["dbname"],
            host=config["host"],
            port=config["port"],
            user=config["user"],
            password=config["password"],
        )
    except Exception as err:
        print(err, err)
    return conn


print("start")
conn = create_conn(config=conf)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `pg_group`;")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Any tips on how to diagnose what could be going wrong? Assuming the code is correct, what networking issues could I be running into?

If it's relevant, the Node public and private IP addresses shown in the console do not match the one given in the error message.

EDIT: I do start an ssh tunnel when running the code. Tried the code with both the SSH port and the default redshift port.

```
Host staging-bridge
  HostName xx.xx.xxx.xx
  User user
  LocalForward 4450 redshift-instance.asdf.us-west-14.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jumphost_key
```

EDIT: Setting `port` in `conf` to local host works. Guess I didn't understand the SSH set up well.

Comment: You said the SQL client connects "via ssh". Please explain what that means. Are you using SSH port forwarding with a bastion host/jump box? Or are you doing an `ssh` command into an EC2 server, and then running the SQL Client on that server? Also, are you running the Python code on your local computer, or on an EC2 instance in the same VPC as the Redshift server?

Comment: SSH port != Postgres port so you are comparing apples and oranges. The error message indicates either: a) The Postgres server is not running. b) It is running and some firewall is not allowing the Postgres port through.

Comment: Thanks. ssh port forwarding with a jump box. When running the python code locally I create an ssh tunnel. It will eventually be deployed to ECS in the same VPC. I'll edit with the ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Got it. I was trying to connect to the redshift host vs my own local with the port forwarded. Thanks for the tips.